# How to apply multiple shaders to one 3D object, using Three.js and WebGL

Tags: three.js, 3d, shader

I'm playing around with WebGL. The following is a working example with a 3D object using Three.js. Is it possible to add multiple shaders to one 3D object, like this one? It would be highly appreciated if you can share some knowledge.

I just learned from one pro that helped with solutions to applying one shader material to 3D object. However, I'm curious about whether to add multiple shaders to give more effects to the 3D object.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>OBJ loader</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: Monospace;
                background-color: #fff;
                color: #fff;
                margin: 0px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            #info {
                color: #fff;
                position: absolute;
                top: 10px;
                width: 100%;
                text-align: center;
                z-index: 100;
                display:block;
            }
            #info a, .button { color: #f00; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>


        <script src="http://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/loaders/OBJLoader.js"></script>

        <script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            var clock = new THREE.Clock();
            var delta = clock.getDelta(); // seconds.
            var rotateAngle = Math.PI / 2 * delta;   // pi/2 radians (90 degrees) per second
            var container, stats;

            var camera, scene, renderer, texture;

            var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;

            var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
            var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

            init();
            animate();
    //var texture = new THREE.Texture();
                new THREE.OBJLoader( ).load( 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/40480/head.obj', function ( object ) {

                    object.traverse( function ( child ) {

                        if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {

                            child.material.map = texture;

                        }

                    } );

    
                  
                    scene.add( object );

                } );

            function init() {

                container = document.createElement( 'div' );
                document.body.appendChild( container );

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 15, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000 );
                camera.position.z = 100;

                // scene

                scene = new THREE.Scene();

                var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x111130 );
                scene.add( ambient );

                var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffeeff );
                directionalLight.position.set( 1, 1,0.5 );
                scene.add( directionalLight );

    
        

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );

                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

            }

            function onWindowResize() {
                windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
                windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            }

            function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {
                mouseX = ( event.clientX - windowHalfX ) / 2;
                mouseY = ( event.clientY - windowHalfY ) / 2;
            }

            function animate() {
                requestAnimationFrame( animate );
                render();
            }

            function render() {
             

                camera.position.x += ( mouseX - camera.position.x ) * .05;
                camera.position.y += ( - mouseY - camera.position.y ) * .05;

                camera.lookAt( scene.position );

                renderer.render( scene, camera );
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, rendering a mesh with multiple materials is possible in `three.js` if the geometry defines proper [groups](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=bufferge#api/en/core/BufferGeometry.groups) data. However you normally render different parts of the mesh with distinct materials. E.g. when having a character model, you would render the skin with one material and the cloths with a different one.

You don't want to use this approach to combine or stack effects. Instead, you have to implement a single custom shader that includes all effects that you want to apply on the surface.

Comment: Hi Mugen87, thanks for your input. The example on Codepen (https://codepen.io/jpdurham/pen/QELJxP) could explain the ideas. It renders different meshes with different shader materials using a parameter array. Yes, I want to apply different shaders to one object, like the human head. For a beginner like me, it's pretty difficult to implement a single shader with all effects. Because it needs to assign particular vertices and colors. If you have any tutorial for reference, please let me know. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi Mugen87, can I ask you one question? If I want to apply one shader just to half of the human head and the other shader to the other part of the head, do you know how to? It's a clear-cut line between the two. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Like mentioned above, you have to use the `groups` property of the geometry to divide the data into two groups (one for each material). A common problem is to organize the face order such that the first faces define the first logical part of your object and the last faces the other one. If possible, it's probably best to author your model in a tool like Blender and export it as two separate meshes grouped together.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It would be easier to divide the object into two, using tools like Blender, not WebGL.